# How to parse template string literal type to get the components

Tags: typescript

Maybe without using `as`: How can I

```
type F = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type R = '11' | '22' | '33'

type P = `${F}${R}`


const p: P = `a11`

// is there a better way to parse this string?
function getFR(p: P): [F, R] {
  return [p[0] as F, p.slice(1) as R]
}

console.log(getFR(p))
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UDkBDJUA+yBG6tIGMkBYAKDNEigCUFkBGevZAJheaQGZOTzTLoABToADACQBvGAF9J1aSLJLSBAPYA7AM7AoYAFxRhiESkaK+AegtQAlpqjAAFhABO0FFGwRgwV1ADuKCAOqrooLprQTnZQ2i426gDmAPxkAGYAruoEwDYaUIneMNQAFPqGAJQGANowADQ0ALpQEmRQUG7AGS7qUNVg1QAMzSj29boAdJoANjYEECX0FVCjTWTSympaqtMQE9OqiSWFwMVlFRVAA

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand - everything seems OK there. What is the problem?

Comment: It is working, just I wondered if there is a special easier way to parse this string to it's subtypes

Comment: ohh right... there is, but what you parse should still be a type, not a value, does [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20201028#example/string-manipulation-with-template-literals) help you?

Comment: Typescript is Javascript + Types. You write the code the way you would in Javascript, and add type annotations so the compiler can check your code. If the code in your question is the way you would solve your problem in Javascript, then it's also the way you solve it in Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

For a typescript-specific solution, if you are willing to to use strings as *types*, not values, you can use `infer` in [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) (see "we can infer from substitution positions" part), like in:

```ts
type F = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type R = '11' | '22' | '33'

type P = `${F}${R}`

type ExtractFR<T extends P> = T extends `${infer f extends F}${infer r extends R}` ? [f, r] : never;

type fr = ExtractFR<'a11'> // ['a', '11']
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/NnbqdN)

Comment: No I want to work on value level, simply parse a string and let the values have the right types.

Comment: Right, then I don't think your original solution can be significantly improved. I suppose those values come from somewhere else (e.g., user input) so there's just javascript, typescript preprocessing is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

[www.typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=28&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYlC8UDkBDJUA+yBG6tIGMkAoY0SKAJQWQEZa9kAmJxpAZnZLPGgAUaAAwAkAbxgBfMZQmDSBAPYA7AM7AoYAFxQBiQSnpzii1eogAPYACcUBdYgA8AFSgXgEJQBMVOgHwAKLSgnAEptAG0YABpKAF0EXyhRYihUkzUoTxRgFG0UJRAacLBwgAZYqI0AOhUAGwBLAgh-WhDYgG4U1KsIYABXKyVM7JROiVJjZRUFWogq2oUAc383Gzt-ACIDWg2QkKA)

```js
type F = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

type R = '11' | '22' | '33'

type P = `${F}${R}`

const p: P = `a11`

const extract = <T extends P>(p: T): [F,R] => {
   const data: any = [p[0], p.slice(1)];
   return data;
}


console.log(extract("a11"))
```

as you see above you dont have to specify any casting as the method return `:[F,R]` will cast the data automatically. You still have to create a variable of type `any` though